# Problem with triggering a segue with the "return" key on the iPhone keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

Task: I have login and password text fields, what needs to be done:

After entering a login in the text Field and pressing the "return" button, the pointer should go to the password text Field, here the "return" button should call `@IBAction func logInButtonPressed()` (where it checks that the password/login is correct) **and will trigger the segue.**

Here's how I did it:

```
extension MainViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldReturn (_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == loginTextField {
            passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            logInButtonPressed()
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showVC", sender: nil)
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

**Problem:
The pointer goes from the Login text field, to the Password text field, but the "return" button does nothing.**

I specified the correct Identifier,
the "Log In" button itself works correctly,
BUT the segue does not work if I use the "return" button

What could be the problem, I have already rechecked everything a hundred times, searched for other questions on SO and found nothing.

**[Photo of storyboard with segue settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNNpe.jpg)**
[code of `logInButtonPressed()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kPRe.png)

Many thanks in advance

UPD: The problem was that I didn't write a delegate for the Password text field in viewDidLoad().
Thanks for Help!)

Comment: What does this function do logInButtonPressed. kindly post code of this function.Also make sure you have set the delegate of password textfield.

Comment: Is `performSegue(withIdentifier: "showVC", sender: nil)` called? Did you implement `prepare(for:sender:)`? Is it called? Did you implement `shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`? Is it called?

Comment: @HammerClass now I am added photo

Comment: @Larme  I have implemented both "prepare" and "performSegue" 
prepare works as the Log In button works, segue does not work from the keyboard only. I don't quite understand how to check "Is it called" ?
and what is the difference between "performSegue" and "shouldPerformSegue" ?

Comment: If should `shouldPerformSegue` returns no, then the segue isn't performed. It could be why it's doesn't work. The `prepare` could ensure that it's doing the performSegue, since it will call it before really doing the segue. And to see if it the method is called, put logs in the `else` and inside the other methods... If you implemented both methods, can you share them? Also, in the loginButtonPressed(), shouldn't you NOT performSegue is you show the alert?

Comment: I create delegate for password field and now everything works, thank you all!)